# Linear transformation proof-subspace and range

Tags: linear-algebra

Linear algebra
Let T be a linear transformation T : V->W and let U be a subspace of V. Prove that T(U) is a subspace of range(T).

Picture of the problem:

[image]

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck? Do you understand the definition of a "subspace"?

Comment: I am getting stuck on everything. I do not understand the definition of subspace.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Make sure you understand all definitions. With that, it suffices to argue that the following is true:

- If $u$ is a vector in $U$ and $k$ is a number, then there exists a vector $v \in U$ for which $T(v) = k T(u)$.  Why does $v = ku$ fit this requirement?
- If $u_1,u_2$ are vectors in $U$, then there is a third vector $v \in U$ for which $T(v) = u_1 + u_2$. Why does $v = u_1 + u_2$ fit this requirement?

Comment: Why does v=ku fit this requirement? Because it is closed under scalar multiplication. Why does v=u1+u2 fit this requirement? Because it is closed under vector addition.

Comment: Do you understand why this is enough to conclude that $T(U)$ is a subspace?